# Which partitions to delete for uninstalling ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, partitioning

I want to uninstall Ubuntu. Here is a screen shot of my partitions:[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsoVs.png)

Please help me find out which partitions to delete. I installed Ubuntu in legacy and windows 10 is in UEFI.

Comment: I'd say /dev/sda9 /dev/sda/10 but don't forget to restore your MBR otherwise you won't be able to get into Windows from boot

Comment: What is MBR? How to restore it? And pls see that injury and grin are installed in legacy while my windows 10 is in UEFI.

Comment: Two questions that are easily Google-able, much like your question everything you've written is a duplicate elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Delete /dev/sda9 and /dev/sda10. I'm not sure if this will delete your bootloader as your setup is very confusing. So to be safe, boot windows 10 and restore your windows bootloader like this:

```
bootsect /nt60 drive_letter: /mbr
```

Drive letter of course has to be replaced with the drive letter where your operating system resides, so probably the command will look like this for you:

```
bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr
```

Then you can boot any partitioning tool of your choice and safely delete the ubuntu partitions.

Comment: Links may die, include steps in your written answer